# wxwidgets error WINDOWS.H already included

Tags: c++, mfc, wxwidgets

I have created simple wxwidgets dialog(must include "wx/wxprec.h" first) but also want to re-use some common code from another application which requires these headers:

```
#include "wx/wxprec.h"

#include <afxwin.h>
#include <afxext.h>
#include <afxdisp.h>
#include <afxdtctl.h>
#include <afxcmn.h>
#include <afxsock.h>
#include <afxmt.h>
```

but then I got these error:

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxv_w32.h(16): fatal error C1189: #error :  WINDOWS.H already included.  MFC apps must not #include <windows.h>
```

Any ideas how can I include these MFC files in wxwidgets project?

Comment: Change the order of the #includes, afxwin.h needs to be first.  Whether two different class libraries that do the same thing can come to a good end, well, maybe.  Big maybe.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Well, wxWidgets require to include wx.h or wxprec.h BEFORE windows.h, so seems like I should avoid using mfc based code in wxwidgets project and should re-implement  that functionality using wxWidgets.

Answer (score 1):

The comment by Hans Passant is correct, if you have to use both MFC and wxWidgets together, you must include the MFC headers first. See the wxWidgets [MFC sample](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/WX_3_0_2/samples/mfc/mfctest.cpp#L64) for a working example.

Comment: Well, the problem is that in that case I will get wxWidget related errors. And even if I will include "wx/msw/winundef.h" after mfc related headers include, I will get errors like this:
error C2664: 'GetModuleFileNameA' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'wxStringTypeBuffer<T>' to 'LPSTR' 
or
error C2664: 'UnregisterClassA' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const wchar_t *' to 'LPCSTR'

Comment: This looks like a mismatch between `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` or something like this. Make sure you define both in your project settings.